# Naming a method that converts raw data into an object

Tags: data-structures, naming

Say you have data in the format:

```
name=john;age=33;gender=male
```

What would you call a method that converts data like that into an an object / associative array?

I've been thinking about:
- unserialize_variables
- parse_variables

Comment: I think that you mean "what would you call" rather than "how would you call"...

Comment: Right, thanks for the correction!

Comment: Deserializing an associative array? I'd use JSON ;)

Comment: JSON is too complex for what I'm using the data in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeserialisePerson

Comment: The method should with any kind of data - not just person related.

Comment: Yes that's an option but what if I need another "deserialize" method for another data format?

Answer (score 1):

Person.Unserialize?

Answer (score 1):

PersonReader. Works if you change how you persist the person data in the future too.

Answer (score 0):

In two steps:

```
ContainerType person = data.parse();

Employee employee( person["name"], person["age"], person["gender"] );
```